# C++ Type which hold class type

Tags: c++

In Free Pascal I can create class of class which create object from assigned class type. For example:

```
type
  TBaseClass = class
  end;

  TBaseClassType = class of TBaseClass;

  TFooClass = class(TBaseClass)
  end;

  TBarClass = class(TBaseClass)
  end;
```

Now I can declare variable:

```
MyClassType: TBaseClassType;
MyObject: TBaseClass;
```

And usage:

```
// This will create instance of object TFooClass
MyClassType := TFooClass;
MyObject := MyClassType.Create;

// ... and here of TBarClass
MyClassType := TBarClass;
MyObject := MyClassType.Create;
```

How can I do something similar in C++? How to store class type in some var and create object from it (and call it constructor of course)

Regards

Comment: You are looking for inheritance. You should get some good book and refer it maybe or there are a lot of tutorials online too. But for this specific case check: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_inheritance.htm

Comment: I know how inheritance in C++ work, it similar like in Free Pascal. But have a look at `TBaseClassType = class of TBaseClass` . What is C++ equivalent of this declaration?

Comment: @Dibo why don't you start off with a book?

Comment: Maybe that is polymorphism. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_polymorphism.htm

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you can't because types are not first-class objects in C++.

The longer answer is: in some cases you can achieve the same things using templates.

If you have a function where you want to parametrize over the the class type, you can use a template function. So, for example, something similar to what you describe above could be achieved using:

```
template <class MyClassType>
void doSomething() {
  MyClassType myObject = MyClassType();
  /* Do something with myObject */
}

doSomething<TFooClass>();
doSomething<TBarClass>();
```

So, in short, the example you gave above cannot be straightforwardly translated to C++ (because you cannot define a variable to hold a type), but depending on the real problem, similar code might be possible to write.

Comment: Ok, I will try with that. Thanks